# Dataframe Balance not updating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df["Dates"] = DatesforAccrual
df["No of Days"] = NoofDaysinAccrual
df["AccrualCoupon"] = AccruedCoupon
df.loc[0, 'AccrualYield'] = 0

df.loc[0, "Balance"] = 500


for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'AccrualYield'] = df.loc[i-1,'Balance']*df.loc[i+0,'No of Days']* 0.1 / 360
    


for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'Balance'] = df.loc[i-1,'Balance']+df.loc[i+0,'AccrualCoupon']- df.loc[i+0,'AccrualYield']

                                         
print(df)
```

The output is as follows:

```
                 Dates  No of Days  AccrualCoupon  AccrualYield  Balance
0     March 15th, 2020           0       0.000000      0.000000   500.00
1    August 15th, 2020         150       2.083333     20.833333   481.25
2  February 15th, 2021         180       2.500000           NaN      NaN
3       May 19th, 2021          94       1.305556           NaN      NaN
```

The value for AccrualYield and Balance has been calculated for only 1 row. Can someone help me so that the remaining rows are updated accordingly. Expected Output as per below

```
                 Dates  No of Days  AccrualCoupon  AccrualYield  Balance
0     March 15th, 2020           0       0.000000      0.000000   500.00
1    August 15th, 2020         150       2.083333     20.833333   481.25
2  February 15th, 2021         180       2.500000         24.06   459.69
3       May 19th, 2021          94       1.305556         12.00   448.99
```

Comment: you really can achieve this logic without loops. maybe add a sample data to illustrate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The accrual yield starting row 2 will be calculated from previous date balance. The balance starting as from row2 will be (Balance from previous row+ AccrualCoupon for same row - AccrualYield for same row). Expected output shared above

Comment: I haven't really thought much about this but indexing things by `i+0` is weird. Did you mean + something other than zero?

Comment: Ok, I read the code now. The issue is that you're doing things in separate `for`loops. In the first loop, first iteration - it will find a value for `Balance` in the first row (index 0), so it will be able to fill the `AccrualYield`. But from the second iteration on  you'll have no values for `Balance` in  the previous row.
Just put both attributions in the same for-loop (first the `AccrualYield`. then the `Balance`)

Comment: @vmg . Many thanks for the valuable help. It is working as expected